# ¿Cómo mostrar una lista como string?

Tags: c

Me encuentro realizando un programa que es un ABM de músicos, el tema es que yo le doy al usuario que ingrese el tipo de orquesta al que pertenece:

1. Sinfónica
2. Filarmónica
3. Cámara

Pero cuando quiero listar la orquesta (Que lleva además nombre y lugar), sólo aparece el número que haya ingresado, cómo podría hacer para listar el nombre del tipo? No sé si me explique bien.. En vez de que aparezca: **1, 2 o 3**, me gustaría que aparezca sinfónica, filarmónica o cámara.

Estoy desarrollando el programa en C, me piden que el tipo de orquesta sea en int

```
#define tamO 3
typedef struct
{
    char nombre[20];
    char lugar[10];
    int tipo;
    int idOrquesta;
    int isEmpty;

}eOrquesta;`

int altaOrquesta(eOrquesta vec[], int tam, int idOrquesta)
{
    int retorno=0;
    char nombre[20];
    char lugar[10];
    int indice;
    int tipo;
    system("cls");
    printf("****Alta orquesta*****\n\n");
    indice=buscarLibre(vec,tam);
    if(indice==-1)
    {
        printf("\nNo hay lugar disponible!\n");
    }else
    {

        printf("Ingrese nombre de la orquesta: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(nombre);
        printf("\nIngrese lugar de la orquesta:");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(lugar);
        printf("\n\n1. Sinfonica \n2.Filarmonica \n3.Camara\nIngrese tipo de orquesta: ");
        scanf("%d", &tipo);
        vec[indice]=newOrquesta(idOrquesta,nombre,lugar,tipo);
        retorno = 1;
        printf("alta exitosa!!\n");
    }
    return retorno;
}
eOrquesta newOrquesta(int idOrquesta, char nombre[], char lugar[], int tipo)
{
    eOrquesta orque;
    orque.idOrquesta=idOrquesta;
    strcpy(orque.nombre,nombre);
    strcpy(orque.lugar,lugar);
    orque.tipo=tipo;
    orque.isEmpty=0;

    return orque;
}
void mostrarUnaOrquesta(eOrquesta x)
{
    printf("%d  %10s    %10s    %d\n",x.idOrquesta,x.nombre,x.lugar,x.tipo);
}

void mostrarOrquestas(eOrquesta vec[],int tam)
{
    int flag = 0;
    system("cls");
    printf("Id   Nombre     Lugar       Tipo\n\n");

    for(int i=0; i < tam; i++)
    {
        if(vec[i].isEmpty==0)
        {
            mostrarUnaOrquesta(vec[i]);
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        printf("\nNo hay orquestas que mostrar!\n");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar parte del código que has desarrollado?

Comment: ahi en la edicion agregue la definicion de la estructura, el alta y mostrar !

Comment: puedes crear una función que usando el número pueda devolver
el texto que deseas.

Comment: y como seria esa funcion? un switch?

Comment: @elgordo87 lo puedes hacer con un switch, else if, con cualquiera de los dos; sin embargo, para este caso, conviene más un operador ternario, ya que únicamente son 3 opciones y así ahorras código.

Answer (score 1):

> Pero cuando quiero listar la orquesta (Que lleva además nombre y lugar), sólo aparece el número que haya ingresado.

Obviamente, pues es lo que pides:

```
void mostrarUnaOrquesta(eOrquesta x)
{
    printf("%d  %10s    %10s    %d\n",x.idOrquesta,x.nombre,x.lugar,x.tipo);
    //      ^^                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^                         Número (no tipo) de la orquesta.
    //          ^^^^                               ^^^^^^^^                Nombre (no tipo) de la orquesta.
    //                  ^^^^                                ^^^^^^^        Lugar (no tipo) de la orquesta.
    //                          ^^                                  ^^^^^^ Tipo (NUMÉRICO) de la orquesta.
}
```

No puedes pedir una cosa al programa y después sorprenderte y lamentarte de que el programa haga exactamente lo que le has pedido.

> ¿Cómo podría hacer para listar el nombre del tipo?

Necesitas una manera de asociar un identificador numérico con una cadena, por ejemplo una función que transforme `eOrquesta.tipo` a cadena:

```
char *tipo_a_nombre(int tipo)
{
    switch (tipo)
    {
        case 1: return "Sinfónica";
        case 2: return "Filarmónica";
        case 3: return "Cámara";
    }
    return "Desconocido";
}
```

Podría usarse así:

```
void mostrarUnaOrquesta(eOrquesta x)
{
    printf("%d  %10s    %10s    %s\n", x.idOrquesta, x.nombre, x.lugar, tipo_a_nombre(x.tipo));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Podrías crear una función que retorne un puntero a un objeto constante de tipo char, de ese modo, podrías imprimir un texto.
Ejemplo:

```
const char* GetNameO(int tipo)
{
   return ((tipo == 1) ? ("Sinfonica") : ((tipo == 2) ? ("Filarmonica ") : ( (tipo == 3) ? ("Camara") : ("Desconocido") )));
 }
```

Usas la función de la siguiente manera:

```
void mostrarUnaOrquesta(eOrquesta x)
{
    printf("%d  %10s    %10s    %d 
  %s\n",x.idOrquesta,x.nombre,x.lugar,x.tipo, GetNameO(x.tipo));
}
```

Como es un código sencillo, podrías ahorrarte la función y hacerlo con una macro:

```
#define GetNameO(tipo) ((tipo == 1) ? ("Sinfonica") : ((tipo == 2) ? ("Filarmonica ") : ( (tipo == 3) ? ("Camara") : ("Desconocido") )))
```

Su modo de uso es igual como se llamó anteriormente la función.

Comment: Cualquier tipo diferente de 1 o 2 será `"Camara"`. No creo que eso sea correcto.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Está bien el código. Solo se debe validar al momento de pedir el "tipo" por teclado, si está en el rango de 1 a 3, de lo contrario, se manda un mensaje de error diciendo que debe ingresar 1, 2 o 3.

Comment: No veo dicho mensaje de error en ningún sitio Dave.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ya corregí el código.